# django form widget number input

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the below code in my forms.py I am trying to get widget on phone to put up an error if the input is not numbers but it does not work. Everything else works. Any reason why the type=number is not pulling up an error on the form?

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('user',)

        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'maxlength':100, 'required': True}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'maxlength': 100, 'required': True}),
            'phone': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'minlength': 10, 'maxlength': 15, 'required': True, 'type': 'number',}),       
            'date_of_birth': forms.DateInput(attrs={'minlength': 10, 'maxlength': 10, 'required': True}),

            'country': CountrySelectWidget(attrs={'country': 'CountrySelectWidget'}),

        }
```

Comment: Did you read this in the documentation [NumberInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.NumberInput)?

Comment: @ettanany i have read it. can you suggest how else i can get the form to validate the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to get widget on phone to put up an error if the input is
>   not numbers but it does not work.

I suspect that your phone number field isnt defined as a integer field in your model, if it was, the validation check would ensure that non integer data isn't entered.

Based on that assumption, you should be over riding the field and not the widget. Either use the [field_classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/) meta attribute or define the field explictly

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phone = forms.IntegerField(validators = [custom_validator,])
```

It also allows you to use a custom validator if required.